# Google Documents: get active paragraph from cursor position

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to write a script that puts the cursor's surrounding text to uppercase and set the enclosing paragraph to HEADING1. 
  I'm able to do the first thing while I can't figure out the way to get the paragraph containing the cursor using the getCursor() method. Here is what I tried:

```
 var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
 var element = cursor.getElement();
 var paragraph = element.asParagraph();
```

However, element is a TEXT element and can't be cast as PARAGRAPH. Is there a way to get the paragraph from the text element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me some time but I got it ;-) Paragraph is the parent of the textElement surrounding the cursor.

I added a couple of log because I was curious ;-)

```
function myFunction() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  var element = cursor.getElement();
  var paragraph = element.getParent().asParagraph();
  var att = paragraph.getAttributes();// optional
  Logger.log(att); // just out of curiosity... if you want to see
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] =
    DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
  paragraph.setAttributes(style);
  var att = paragraph.getAttributes();// optional
  Logger.log(att); // just out of curiosity... if you want to see
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, getParent() is the key :) However your code raises another question... When you set a paragraph to HEADING1, the paragraph is set according to the 'global' HEADING1, not as HEADING1 is defined in the document. I was using setHeading() instead of setAttributes() but the result is the same. Any clue?

Comment: As you say, this raises another question...then raise it in a new thread, it will be more visible. In the mean time consider accepting this one :-)

Comment: Maybe their api has changed, but when I run this code, I get this error: `BODY_SECTION can't be cast to PARAGRAPH.`

Comment: `element.asParagraph();` instead of `element.getParent().asParagraph();` worked for me though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
var surroundingText = cursor.getSurroundingText().getText();
```

surroundingText  will give you the current paragraph.